# Django: Saving uploaded file in specific directory

Tags: python, django

I want to save files that the user uploads in the project directory 'media/documents/(their user id)/filename.pdf'. I tried doing this:

```
def user_directory_path(request, filename):
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(request.user.id, filename)
```

But I get this error:

[image]

I am not sure what to do, I am a bit of a django noob. I appreciate any help!

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser


def user_directory_path(request, filename):
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(request.user.id, filename)


class Contract(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path, default = 'settings.MEDIA_ROOT/documents/default.pdf')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Employer(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contracts_made = models.ForeignKey(Contract, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_joined']

    def __str__(self):
        full_name = str(self.first_name) + " " + str(self.last_name)
        return full_name


class Employee(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    agreed = models.ForeignKey(Contract, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_joined']

    def __str__(self):
        full_name = str(self.first_name) + " " + str(self.last_name)
        return full_name
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import UploadFileForm


def HomePageView(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'model_form_upload.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Contract


class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contract
        fields = ('title', 'file')
```

root/settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for ContractPal project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'sdcmn$--+h_392b0-2-jps$zls4!7p+4mq65e=1q6&#p%l1f!!'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'contract.apps.ContractConfig',
    'django.contrib.sites',
]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ContractPal.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ContractPal.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

#CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

#LOGIN_URL = '/account/login/'

ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'invitations.models.InvitationsAdapter'
```

Comment: You can not access the *requested user* in the *default model function*

Comment: The [***`upload_to`***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) callable takes two parameters, first the ***instance*** that to be saved, and ***filename*** of the uploaded file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function passed to `upload_to` does not take the request as first parameter but the model instance (see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)).

If you want to be able to get the user from a `Contract` you have to save this information in your contract:

```py
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user_id, filename)


class Contract(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path, default = 'settings.MEDIA_ROOT/documents/default.pdf')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Of course, this means that when you create a contract, you have to pass the user as well. For instance:

```py
def some_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    Contract.objects.create(user=request.user, ...)
```